# How to disable Vercel Middleware in specific environment without invoking the middleware?

Tags: next.js, vercel, vercel-middleware

Vercel provides IP / user access control features, but they do not work for my use case. Therefore, I am currently using middleware on my NextJS site hosted on Vercel solely to block unauthorized access to my preview sites based on user IP.

I don't need/want the middleware to run on my production site. To prevent this, I am performing an environment check within the middleware itself, and if production is detected, the middleware exits early. However, performing that check results in a middleware invocation, which I don't want.

As a refresher, here is what the [Vercel docs](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-middleware/middleware-api#config-object) say about middleware:

> Middleware will be invoked for every route in your project. If you only want it to be run on specific paths, you can define those either with a custom matcher config or with conditional statements.
>
> While the config option is the preferred method, as it does not get
> invoked on every request, you can also use conditional statements to
> only run the Middleware when it matches specific paths.

Neither of these approaches allow for environment-specific disabling without invoking the middleware.

Is there a good way in which I can "disable" middleware on my production site? Or is there another approach I can use as a workaround? Perhaps by modifying package.json or build pipeline steps?

Comment: Why are you not generating the config based on the environment variables? They should be available in `process.env` so you shouldn't need the middleware to run to access them.

Comment: Answering myself here after trial and error: because it is not possible. Adding a conditional expression into the `config.matcher` declaration is not allowed and will not be parsed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage a prebuild step in `package.json` that uses environment variables to create/delete/modify `middleware.json`:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "node build-files.js"
}
```

**build-files.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');

if (process.env.GENERATE_MIDDLEWARE === 'true') {
  const content = 'async function middleware(req) {console.log("Middleware is running")}';
  fs.writeFileSync('./src/middleware.js', content, 'utf8');
  console.log('middleware.js file created');
} else {
  if (fs.existsSync('./src/middleware.js')) {
    fs.unlinkSync('./src/middleware.js');
    console.log('middleware.js file removed ');
  }
}
```

Comment: Build step, yes. But instead of writing the middleware file out I'd rather have it already in the repo and then either rename it (from `middleware_disabled.js`) to opt-in or delete it (having it named `middleware.js`) to opt-out on environment setup.